# jquery change background of one element at a time

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, I am using this function below to change the background of one element at a time. I have it working great, considering I got it from here anyway, but what I would like is that when you click on the second or third child after the class has been added, it will remove the class and add the active class back to the first child.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.innernav li:first-child a').addClass('back');
});
$("a").click(function () {
    $('a').removeClass('back');
    $(this).addClass('back');
});
```

Quite simply, I would like it to revert to the first-child rule when an element has been clicked for a second time. The reason it is like this is because, on my site, when you click one, it will display content below it. When a different element is clicked, it will display new content and hide the previous, but when clicked again, it'll return the content back to the original content that displays when the page initially loads. I will include that function in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W3sXD/3/) for you guys to have a better understanding of what is actually going on. I haven't been able to get the toggleDisplay to work in jsFiddle, but it does work fine normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking if the class `'back'` is already present (aka the link has been clicked before). If it is, then revert to the first-child rule:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.innernav li:first-child a').addClass('back');
});
$("a#bg").click(function(){
    var isSecondClick = $(this).hasClass('back');
    $('a').removeClass('back');
    if (isSecondClick) {
        $('.innernav li:first-child a').addClass('back');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('back');
    }
});
```

[Your fiddle, updated.](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/W3sXD/5/)

Comment: oh, wow. easy as that. I'm a bit new to jQuery, but that is really easy to understand. I had no idea it was that relative to what you are _actually_ doing haha but thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for. And thanks for fixing the toggleDisplay for jsFiddle. It wasn't working for me for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, to fix it for jsFiddle, I changed the second combobox in the right to `no wrap - in <body>`. This means the JavaScript part will be insertted right before the end of the  `<body` tag in the final generated HTML.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't see that option in the left column. Thanks again. I will actually give you full recognition on my site for that. You just did in 5 minutes what has taken me over a month to get around to. I guess I should start picking up books on jQuery. JavaScript is easy for me, but jQuery is a lot simpler and requires a lot less code.

Comment: Hehe, wow, thanks a lot, but you really don't have to do that. It just happened to be me this time, but there are a lot of smart guys here (with much more knowledge than me) who will come to help anytime. I'm learning jQuery myself as well, and knowing JavaScript helps a lot. As you said, some tutorials/books will get you going. Although I see you are already pretty advanced. I guess this was one of those cases where we have gotten so used to the code we may miss some simple stuff and a third person can help :)

Comment: yeah, like yesterday, my question had a simple issue where i forgot the `.` on a CSS element. That was a bit embarrassing, but I'm thankful that got fixed along with the issue I had originally asked in yesterday's question. I just need to hurry up and get my site done so I can start making websites. I know people are like, why start a business when you can't even fix your own? Because web design is never done. New idea, and I had never known it could actually be done. Plus not a lot of people ask for jQuery widgets and scripts. I can do almost anything in CSS I can do in JS