# Toggle class of background-color but only one element at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple elements that change to the background-color red when clicked. However, I need *only* the last element that is clicked on to be red and all the other elements to have reverted back to their former background-color.

Right now, if you click all the buttons, they will all be red. Here's the toy version of my code.

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style media="screen">
    .buttons {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px white;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #buttonGallery {
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      width: 155px;
    }

    #button_1 {
      background-color: #ffcc66;
    }

    #button_2 {
      background-color: #99ffff;
    }

.buttons:hover {
      background-color: red !important;
      border: solid 3px black !important;
    }

    .selected {
      background-color: red !important;
      border: solid 3px black !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="buttonGallery">
    <div id="button_1" class="buttons">
      <p>button_1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="button_2" class="buttons">
      <p>button_2</p>
    </div>

</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.buttons').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This link seemed helpful but I'm new to coding and haven't been able to replicate the code outside of jsFiddle: [jquery change background of one element at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256152/jquery-change-background-of-one-element-at-a-time)

Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just clear all the buttons of selected before adding the class.

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style media="screen">
    .buttons {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px white;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #buttonGallery {
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      width: 155px;
    }

    #button_1 {
      background-color: #ffcc66;
    }

    #button_2 {
      background-color: #99ffff;
    }

.buttons:hover {
      background-color: red !important;
      border: solid 3px black !important;
    }

    .selected {
      background-color: red !important;
      border: solid 3px black !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="buttonGallery">
    <div id="button_1" class="buttons">
      <p>button_1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="button_2" class="buttons">
      <p>button_2</p>
    </div>

</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.buttons').click(function() {
      $('.buttons').removeClass("selected");
      $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's the solution.
you can simply remove the class from all the buttons first and then toggle the class of the current button

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style media="screen">
    .buttons {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px white;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #buttonGallery {
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      width: 155px;
    }

    #button_1 {
      background-color: #ffcc66;
    }

    #button_2 {
      background-color: #99ffff;
    }

.buttons:hover {
      background-color: red !important;
      border: solid 3px black !important;
    }

    .selected {
      background-color: red !important;
      border: solid 3px black !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="buttonGallery">
    <div id="button_1" class="buttons">
      <p>button_1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="button_2" class="buttons">
      <p>button_2</p>
    </div>

</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.buttons').click(function() {
      $(".buttons").not($(this)).removeClass("selected");
      $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```